# Identify First Chance Exceptions caused by Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am subscribing to the AppDomain.FirstChanceException event and, when an exception occurs, writing the stack trace to the Debug window in Visual Studio 2012 (and also a trace file). This mechanism is used to spot potential problems during development, but is not used in production builds of the code.

However, I am getting first chance exceptions logged that only occur when debugging in Visual Studio and hitting a breakpoint. For example:

```
First chance exception of type [ThreadAbortException]
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.Main.ThrowCrossThreadMessageException(String formatString)
at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.GetWindowTextLength(HandleRef hWnd)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_WindowText()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.get_WindowText()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Text()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.get_Text()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ToString()
at Test.Form1.<Form1_Load>b__3(Object obj)
at System.Action`1.Invoke(T obj)
at Test.MyClass.<DoStuff>b__13(Object obj)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Note that my code is not interacting with the form at any point.

My question is whether there is a reliable way of determining that the exception was purely as a result of debugging, so my logging code can ignore it? I could look for the string 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger' in the stack trace, but I'm not sure that will capture all cases where the problem might occurs.

To be clear, I am not interested in the cause of the specific exception shown, only in finding a way of weeding out exceptions caused by debugging.

I can't post the code, because it won't make sense without some supporting code that I cannot post. I am not seeking to address the exception - which happens when debugging, but not otherwise - only to determine whether I can identify first chance exceptions originating from the debugger in the event handler for the AppDomain.FirstChanceException event.

Here is a naive example though:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Oops { get { throw new Exception("Oops"); } }
}
```

Breakpoint after the creation of foo and expand foo in the locals window. Obviously this will cause an exception, but run the code outside visual studio and it won't.

Comment: What do you do in `DoStuff`? - it looks like you are actually trying to read something from a form via a thread pool work item, which is a no-no.

Comment: As I mentioned, my code is not interacting with the form in any way. When not debugging, but still logging first chance exceptions, the exception is not thrown. I wonder if what is happening is that on encountering the breakpoint, Visual Studio attempts to populate something in the local or auto watch window which does read from the form.

Comment: Can you post the source for DoStuff?